# How to make my android phone to read the Apple Wallet via NFC

Tags: nfc

I want to implement service, using ECP1.0 2.0 protocol to be able to read the Apple WALLET NFC tag, i.e. I want to enable my android device as NFC terminal, that can read Apple Wallet NFC tag.

I tried going through the apple developer documentation, and open source from Koramax and Springcard but not found anything relevant to make Android device (which has NXP chip) as terminal reader

Comment: Apple Wallet should be emulating a NFC Type 4 Tag so you can use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep to read it but you would need to know the AID's they are using and what ISO 7816 APDU's they support.